# How can I input a set start and end time using Chrono or ctime libaray

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++-chrono

I'm having a hard time understanding time with in c++. I want to input values for time like this.

```
time_t  t = time(0);
tm* now = localtime(&t);
cin >> now->tm_wday >> now->tm_mon >> now->tm_year;
```

I feel this is a wrong way of doing this. my main objective is to try create a start time and date and an end time and date and have the object run until the given end time and date. With inputting time values confuses me and would like a little help steering me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `std::tm*` returned from `std::localtime` is not a good place to store data in. Note that all the different offsets in the `std::tm` struct are well [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm).

Using only year, month and weekday as you do isn't really enough. There are more than one day in each month having a Saturday for example.

You can do like this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::tm now{}; // declare and initialize your own tm
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point cc;

    std::cout << "enter\nyear month day\n";

    std::cin >> now.tm_year >> now.tm_mon >> now.tm_mday;

    // compensate for offsets
    now.tm_year -= 1900;
    now.tm_mon -= 1;

    // convert to std::time_t
    std::time_t n = std::mktime(&now);

    // here you get a chrono time_point from the user input
    cc = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(n);

    // convert back to std::time_t
    n = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(cc);

    // print the result
    std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&n), "%FT%T") << "\n";
}
```

Example input/output:

```
enter
year month day
2019 11 20
2019-11-20T00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I understand how to input time.

Comment: @MarcusWilliams You are welcome! Be sure to add sanity checks after the user has entered values. If you put invalid values in, it may break.